# Create folder on VCenter server using Ansible

Tags: ansible, vcenter

- Problem statement:

  1. Given a folder name, Check if it exists on VCenter Server and if not create the same.
  2. Clone a VM from template under this folder.

For example, I want to clone a VM under "Administrator Desktops" as shown in the following image:
[Click here to see the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hHQnf.jpg)

The script below is cloning a VM from specified template and placing the VM into specified folder. But fails when that folder does not exist on VCenter server:

> ```
> ---
> - hosts: localhost
>   connection: local
>   sudo: false
>   user: root
>   gather_facts: false
>   serial: 1
>
>   vars_files:
>     - createVmVars.yml
>
>   tasks:
>     - name: Deploying VM from template.
>       vsphere_guest:
>         vcenter_hostname: "{{vcenter_hostname}}"
>         username: "{{vcenter_username}}"
>         password: "{{vcenter_password}}"
>         guest: "{{guest_name}}"
>         from_template: yes
>         template_src: "{{template_src}}"
>         cluster: "{{cluster}}"
>         resource_pool: "{{resource_pool}}"
>         vm_extra_config:
>           folder: "{{folder_name}}"
> ```

Need help to make this script flexible so that when the folder does not exists, it should create the mentioned folder and then clone the VM under this folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this Ansible module to create folder in vsphere:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

DOCUMENTATION = '''
---
author: "Shashank Awasthi"
module: vsphere_create_folder
short_description: Create a folder on VCenter if it does not exist
description:
  - This module requires login to VCenter Server
  - This module requires pysphere python module installed
  - This module creates a folder on mentioned VCenter Server
  - This module does not create any folder if the folder with the same name is already existing on the VCenter Server
  - This module supports nesting upto only 2 levels
version_added: "1.2"
options:
  host:
    description:
      - The vsphere Server on which the folder is to be created
    required: true
  login:
    description:
      - The login name to authenticate on VSphere
    required: true
  password:
    description:
      - The password to authenticate VSphere
    required: true
  folder_name:
    description:
      - The folder name which is to be created
    required: true
  parent_folder_name:
    description:
      The name of parent folder under which the folder_name is residing.
    required: true
  datacenter_name:
    description:
      - The name of the datacenter where the folder is to be created
    required: true
examples:
  - description: create the folder with name NewDeployments
    code:
       - local_action: vsphere_create_folder host=$eszserver login=$esxlogin password=$esxpassword folder_name=$folder_name
parent_folder_name=$parent_folder_name  datacenter_name=$dc_name
notes:
  - This module ought ot be run from a system which can access vsphere directly
'''

import sys

try:
        import pysphere
        from pysphere import *
        from pysphere.resources import VimService_services as VI
except ImportError:
        print "failed=true, msg=Pysphere Python module not available"
        sys.exit(1)

def main():
        module = AnsibleModule(
                argument_spec = dict(
                        host =  dict(requred = True),
                        login = dict(required = True),
                        password = dict(required = True),
                        folder_name = dict(required = True),
                        parent_folder_name =  dict(required = True),
                        datacenter_name = dict(required = True)
                )
        )

        host = module.params.get('host')
        login = module.params.get('login')
        password = module.params.get('password')
        folder_name = module.params.get('folder_name')
        parent_folder_name = module.params.get('parent_folder_name')
        datacenter_name = module.params.get('datacenter_name')

        server = pysphere.VIServer()
        try:
                server.connect(host,login,password)
        except Exception, e:
                module.fail_json(msg = 'Failed to connect to %s: %s' % (host, e))


        def createFolder(vm_folder,folder_name):
                try:
                        request = VI.CreateFolderRequestMsg()
                        _this = request.new__this(vm_folder)
                        _this.set_attribute_type(vm_folder.get_attribute_type())
                        request.set_element__this(_this)
                        request.set_element_name(folder_name)
                        server._proxy.CreateFolder(request)
                except pysphere.ZSI.FaultException, e:
                        pass

        try:
                datacenters = server._get_datacenters()
                dc = datacenters[datacenter_name]

                dc_props = VIProperty(server,dc)
                vm_folder = dc_props.vmFolder._obj

                createFolder(vm_folder,parent_folder_name)

                folders =  server._retrieve_properties_traversal(property_names=['name'], from_node =  dc, obj_type = 'Folder')

                for f in folders:
                        if f.PropSet[0].Val == parent_folder_name:
                                vm_folder = f.Obj
                                break
                createFolder(vm_folder,folder_name)
        except Exception, e:
                module.fail_json(msg = "failed to create folder: %s" % e)




        module.exit_json(changed = True, folder = folder_name, parent_folder = parent_folder_name)

#<<INCLUDE_ANSIBLE_MODULE_COMMON>>
main()
```